# MySQL Count Comma Delimited

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like this:

table_events

```
+------+----------+----------------------+
| ID   | Title    | Employees            |
+------+----------+----------------------+
| 1    | Event1   | john,james           |
+------+----------+----------------------+
| 2    | Event2   | sarah,jessica        |
+------+----------+----------------------+
```

table_check_in

```
+------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| ID   | Time     | EventID  | By                  |
+------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 1    | 08:30    | 1        | john                |
+------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 2    | 08:30    | 1        | james               |
+------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 3    | 09:30    | 1        | john                |
+------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 4    | 10:30    | 2        | sarah               |
+------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 5    | 10:35    | 2        | sarah               |
+------+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

table_problems

```
+------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
| ID   | Comment        | EventID  | By                  |
+------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
| 1    | Broken door    | 1        | john                |
+------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
| 2    | Slippery floor | 1        | john                |
+------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
| 3    | Leaking tap    | 1        | john                |
+------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
| 4    | Broken window  | 2        | jessica             |
+------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
| 5    | Broken glass   | 2        | jessica             |
+------+----------------+----------+---------------------+
```

I would like to print something like this:

```
+------+----------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| ID   | Title    | Employees     | Count_Check_In    | Count_Problems    |
+------+----------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1    | Event1   | john,james    | john:2,james:1    | john:3,james:0    |
+------+----------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 2    | Event2   | sarah,jessica | sarah:2,jessica:0 | sarah:0,jessica:2 |
+------+----------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I know this problem would be trivial if the database was designed properly, but we don't have the luxury of an application rewrite at the moment.

Comment: Look up  `group_concat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT to get a result. Here is an example. The only thing missed is employees with 0 check ins or problems.

```
SELECT ID, Title,Employees,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(check_in.`By`,':',check_in.cnt)) 
                   as Count_Check_In,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(problems.`By`,':',problems.cnt)) 
                   as Count_Problems       
FROM table_events
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EventID,`By`, COUNT(*) as cnt 
        FROM table_check_in
        GROUP BY EventID,`By`) as check_in
      ON table_events.ID = check_in.EventID  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EventID,`By`, COUNT(*) as cnt 
        FROM table_problems
        GROUP BY EventID,`By`) as problems
      ON table_events.ID = problems.EventID  
GROUP BY table_events.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/CBNNI97307)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You need to initially get all the employees for each event id from check in and problem tables by using a `union`.

Then `left join` the counts from each of check in and problems table to the previous result to get the 0 counts as well.

Finally use a `group_concat` to get the result in one row for each event id.

```
select te.id,te.title,te.employees
,group_concat(concat(t.`By`,':',coalesce(tccnt.cnt,0))) count_check_in
,group_concat(concat(t.`By`,':',coalesce(tpcnt.cnt,0))) count_problems
from table_events te 
left join (select eventid,`By` from table_check_in
           union
           select eventid,`By`from table_problems) t on te.id = t.eventid
left join (select eventid,`By`,count(*) cnt from table_check_in group by eventid,`By`) tccnt on tccnt.eventid = t.eventid and tccnt.`By`=t.`By`
left join (select eventid,`By`,count(*) cnt from table_problems group by eventid,`By`) tpcnt on tpcnt.eventid = t.eventid and tpcnt.`By`=t.`By`
group by te.id,te.title,te.employees
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/MLSP48236)** (thanks to @valex for setting up the schema)